# JavaScript .sort() don't sort my data correctly, Please explain

Tags: javascript, sorting, higher-order-functions

I have a two list which is rendering with .forEach(). You can see on the left top corner **Exams** and **Lessons**. But when I am trying to sort my list due to **Points**. It is work but I can see the result only when switching to my another list (I mean; Lessons list) and come back again I could see it is actually sort. I want to see the result realtime. Can someone please help me ? Maybe the structure is not correct. I tried to sort my dummy data and later give the sorted data to the loop and render again but it is not work or I cant do correctly.. Here is the  **CodePen Live version** (https://codepen.io/ruslancik/pen/xxVGEBE?editors=0010)

```
//Dummy data for each list
    const exams = [
        {
            bal: 681,
            qrup: 'II qrup',
            zaman: 40,
            tarix: '22 iyul 2020, 17:30',
        },
        {
            bal: 602,
            qrup: 'II qrup',
            zaman: 31,
            tarix: '16 may 2020, 17:30',
        },
        {
            bal: 397,
            qrup: 'II qrup',
            zaman: 63,
            tarix: '20 iyun 2020, 17:30',
        },
        {
            bal: 401,
            qrup: 'II qrup',
            zaman: 49,
            tarix: '25 mart 2020, 17:30',
        }
    ];
    const lessons = [
        {
            bal: 58,
            qrup: 'Azərbaycan dili',
            zaman: 64,
            tarix: '20 iyul 2020, 17:30',
        },
        {
            bal: 75,
            qrup: 'İngilis dili',
            zaman: 63,
            tarix: '14 may 2020, 17:30',
        },
        {
            bal: 75,
            qrup: 'Riyaziyyat',
            zaman: 63,
            tarix: '20 iyun 2020, 17:30',
        },
        {
            bal: 51,
            qrup: 'Azərbaycan dili',
            zaman: 49,
            tarix: '25 mart 2020, 17:30',
        },
        {
            bal: 67,
            qrup: 'Azərbaycan dili',
            zaman: 49,
            tarix: '25 mart 2020, 17:30',
        },
        {
            bal: 53,
            qrup: 'Kimya',
            zaman: 49,
            tarix: '25 mart 2020, 17:30',
        },
        {
            bal: 51,
            qrup: 'Azərbaycan dili',
            zaman: 49,
            tarix: '25 mart 2020, 17:30',
        },
        {
            bal: 62,
            qrup: 'Fizika',
            zaman: 49,
            tarix: '25 mart 2020, 17:30',
        }
    ];
    
    const examSelector = document.getElementById('exam');
    const lessonSelector = document.getElementById('lesson');
    
    examSelector.innerText = `Exams (${exams.length})`;
    lessonSelector.innerText = `Lessons (${lessons.length})`;
    
    
    const resultContainer = document.getElementById('result');
    
    
    window.addEventListener('load', examHandler )
    
    examSelector.addEventListener('click', examHandler )
    
    function examHandler(){
        //color
        examSelector.style.color='rgba(62, 130, 255, 1)';
        lessonSelector.style.color='rgba(4, 37, 96, .3)';
    
    
        const resultList = document.querySelector('.result-list') || document.createElement('DIV');
        resultList.innerHTML = '';
        exams.forEach(item => {
            if (resultList.parentNode) resultList.parentNode.removeChild(resultList);
            resultList.className = 'result-list'
            resultContainer.appendChild(resultList);
            resultList.innerHTML += `
            <ul>
             <li>${item.bal}</li>
             <li>${item.qrup}</li>
             <li>${item.zaman} min</li>
             <li>${item.tarix}</li>
            </ul>
            `
         })
    };
    
    
    lessonSelector.addEventListener('click', lessonHandler )
    
    function lessonHandler() {
        //color
        lessonSelector.style.color='rgba(62, 130, 255, 1)';
        examSelector.style.color='rgba(4, 37, 96, .3)';
    
    
        const resultList = document.querySelector('.result-list') || document.createElement('DIV');
        resultList.innerHTML = '';
        lessons.forEach(item => {
            
            if (resultList.parentNode) resultList.parentNode.removeChild(resultList);
            resultList.className = 'result-list'
            resultContainer.appendChild(resultList);
            resultList.innerHTML += `
            <ul>
            <li>${item.bal}%</li>
            <li>${item.qrup}</li>
            <li>${item.zaman} min</li>
            <li>${item.tarix}</li>
           </ul>
            `
    
         })
    
    };
    
    const resultFilter = document.getElementById('resultFilter');
    // const timeFilter = document.getElementById('timeFilter');
    // const dateFilter = document.getElementById('dateFilter');
    
    
    function dynamicSort(property) {
        var sortOrder = 1;
        if(property[0] === "-") {
             sortOrder = -1;
             property = property.substr(1);
        }
        return function (a,b) {
            var result = (a[property] < b[property]) ? -1 : (a[property] > b[property]) ? 1 : 0;
             return result * sortOrder;
        }
     }
    
    resultFilter.addEventListener('click', function() {
         exams.sort(dynamicSort('bal'))
     })
```

Comment: It looks like you need to call the correct handler function after you sort your data.

Comment: Your `examHandler` and `lessonHandler` do re-render the list in the DOM. Your `resultFilter`'s click handler does not - it only sorts the in-memory array but doesn't display the results.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for your time. I call the **examHandler** inside the **resultFilter** eventlistener for re render data. (as Charles Bamford offer). It is work but when I try to the same thing for lessonHandler it only work for in Lessons list. As you know, it takes the last function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `examHandler()` again after you have sorted the data. Only your JavaScript variable have been changed (sorted) when you click on the element, but the rendered html is not changed. The html is first changed when you go back and forth, hence it is working there because of the rerendering

Comment: `resultFilter.addEventListener('click', function() {
     exams.sort(dynamicSort('bal'))
      examHandler();
 })`
If you mean like this. It is work but if I want to add same functinality to Lessons list like 
`resultFilter.addEventListener('click', function() {
     lessons.sort(dynamicSort('bal'))
      lessonHandler();
 })`
It only takes last event handler as you know.

Comment: @RuslanBairamovi here you have 2 ways to do it.  You could have the lists in 2 different elements, then hide and show the elements when the other list has to be shown, then you can have 2 click handlers so you know which list has been clicked on. The other way of doing it to have a variable where you save which list is being shown, then sort and render the relevant list in the resultfilter click handler

Comment: Thank you for your time @Benjaco. I will try them and let you know about the result.